# How to import a big database from Heroku to local mysql or sqlite3?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, sqlite, heroku, backup

As per title I need to import, but PG backups is giving me strict Postgres SQL that doesn't work with MySQL, also with a non-specified encoding that I guess is UTF-16. Using db:pull takes ages and errors before finishing.
I'd appreciate any suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: I have a similar issue- how to get a backup *without* installing PG locally. You may want to edit your question to include this (as you did in a comment below.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Set up PostgreSQL locally, use [PG backups](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups#exporting_via_a_backup) to copy the data from Heroku to your local machine, then [`pg_restore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html) to import it into your new local PostgreSQL. Then you can copy it from PostgreSQL to MySQL or SQLite locally without having to worry about timeouts. Or, since you'd have a functional PostgreSQL installation after that, just start developing on top of PostgreSQL so that your development stack better matches your deployment stack; developing and deploying on the same database is a good idea.

You're probably getting binary dumps (i.e. [`pg_dump -Fc`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html)) from Heroku, that would explain why the dump looks like some sort of UTF-16 nonsense.

You can use the pgbackups [addon](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups) to export the database dump

```
$ heroku addons:add pgbackups # To install the addon
$ curl -o latest.dump `heroku pgbackups:url` # To download a dump
```

Comment: Hi mu, thanks, but installing PG to develop is what I wanted to avoid. It can be useful to have the same DB in dev, but for most projects, it's just not worth, I'd stick with SQLite3.

Comment: In the end I ended installing PG (or you can use the one shipped with Lion). The process was:

* create a PG user
* restore the dump with pg_restore
* install the **pg** and **taps** gems
* start the taps server on postgres: `taps server postgres://root@localhost/rcp_dev tapsuser tapspassword`
* pull the data to sqlite3 (the same for mysql): `taps pull sqlite://db/development.sqlite3 http://tapsuser:tapspassword@localhost:5000`

Comment: @aledalgrande: Developing on PostgreSQL absolutely is worth it if you're deploying to Heroku. All databases have subtle and not-so-subtle differences (GROUP BY, case sensitivity, booleans, function availability, data types, casting requirements, truncate or raise an exception, ...) and no ORM can protect you from all of them. Save yourself some grief, develop and deploy on the same stack.

Answer (score 21):

Heroku has instructions on how to do this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#restore-to-local-database, which boil down to:

```
$ pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser -d mydb latest.dump
```

where `myuser` is the current user and `mydb` is the current database.

If you're using [Postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/), it's pretty trivial to copy your production database locally. You can leave out `-U myuser` unless you have configured it otherwise, and create a database by running `$ psql -h localhost` and then `CREATE DATABASE your_database_name;` (from the [Postgres.app documentation](http://postgresapp.com/documentation). Then run the above command and you're set.

Answer (score 4):

## Follow these 4 simple steps in your terminal
([Heroku Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export)):

1. Install the Heroku Backup tool:

   ```
   $ heroku addons:add pgbackups
   ```
2. Start using it:

   ```
   $ heroku pgbackups:capture
   ```
3. Download the remote db on Heroku (to your local machine) using curl:

   ```
   $ curl -o latest.dump 'heroku pg:backups public-url'
   ```
4. Load it*:

   ```
   $ pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U YOUR_USERNAME -d DATABASE_NAME latest.dump
   ```

   - get your username and choose the desired database from your config/database.yml file.
   - DATABASE_NAME can be your development/test/production db (Ex. mydb_development)

**That's it!**
**UPDATE:** It is updated to the new interface